# Struts2 isn't loading my webapp...404 error?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jar, struts2

I am a complete newbie to Struts2 and am unable to run anything involving it on tomcat in either eclipse/browser. Tomcat is working fine when I am just mapping servlets/jsp in a web.xml file, but when trying to switch to struts2 I can't get it to work. When I try to run on the server it isn't even going to my index jsp...just loading a 404 error. I followed an online tutorial when I couldn't get my app for my class running and the tutorial I can't get to run either. Here are the jar files I have added to tomcat lib/build path jars -

```
asm-5.0.2.jar             
asm-commons-5.0.2.jar       
asm-tree-5.0.2.jar         
commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar      
commons-io-2.2.jar     
commons-lang3-3.2.jar   
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar   
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar   
freemarker-2.3.19.jar   
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar   
ognl-3.0.6.jar    
struts-core-1.3.10.jar    
struts2-dojo-plugin-2.3.20.jar    
xwork-core-2.3.20.jar
```

filter added to web.xml -

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
  </filter-class>
 </filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

struts xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">

  <action name="hello" 
        class="com.struts2.files.HelloWorldAction" 
        method="execute">
        <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
  </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Any ideas as to why I am getting a 404 when trying to run the app?

Comment: Use the developer tool in your browser to see the request. I guess maybe "/HelloWorld.jsp" is a wrong path.

Comment: PS: set the attribute in <result> "redirect", then you can see your request in Developer tool. Otherwise, it will use default forward method.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you've added the wrong `struts-core-1.3.10.jar` to your *classpath*. That probably belongs to **Struts 1.x**. You need to include the latest `struts2-core-2.x.x.jar` from the **Struts 2** framework.

A typical Struts 2 application has the following jars under `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

```
commons-fileupload-1.2.1
commons-io-1.3.2
commons-logging-1.1
freemarker-2.3.13
junit-3.8.1
ognl-2.6.11
xwork-2.1.2
struts2-core-2.1.6
struts2-convention-plugin-2.1.6 (if using annotations)
```

Try downloading the latests jars from [struts.apache.org](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts2320).

Answer (score 1):

The filter class `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` belongs to `Struts2` but you are using struts1 jar file `struts-core-1.3.10.jar`

As Ravi suggested, download the Jar file from [Struts-2.3.20](https://struts.apache.org/download.cgi)